# Get all previous 11 months based on current month ExtJs 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am completely new to ExtJs. currently i do have requirement to get the current month to display and as well as previous 11 months should be display as tabs within panel.

Here, first thing is , am trying to get the current month and based on current month , i will fetch the remaining previous 11 months to print on console. for exmaple: current month is june 2018, i need to fetch all previous 11 months.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
        var d = new Date();
        alert(d);
        var m = d.getMonth();
        var monthName = m;
        alert(monthNames[monthName]);

    }
});
```

I got current month but not sure how to fetch all remaining months based on current month. can you please advise on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ext.Date.add` function and minus 1 month each time

```
var date = new Date(),
    counter = 11;

while(--counter > 0)
   date = Ext.Date.add(date, Ext.Date.MONTH, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks, This works after changed this :                                          
  while(counter-- > 0){
         date = Ext.Date.add(date, Ext.Date.MONTH, -1);